# Are groovy filters executed the same order as declared in site.xml in Crafter CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, crafter-cms

Are groovy filters executed the same order as declared in site.xml in Crafter CMS?
For example, will filter1 always be executed before filter2?

```
<filter>
            <script>/scripts/filters/filter1.groovy</script>
            <mapping>
                <include>/**</include>
                <exclude></exclude>
            </mapping>
        </filter>
        <filter>
            <script>/scripts/filters/filter2.groovy</script>
            <mapping>
                <include>/**</include>
                <exclude></exclude>
            </mapping>
        </filter>
```

I'm using Crafter 2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they should be exec in the same order as define